# Apply method in instance according to a list python

Tags: python

I have a list (strings) of methods that I would like to apply on an instance (assuming they exist) as following:

```
class PrintStuff:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'hi'

    def do_a(self):
        print(f'{self.name} a')

    def do_b(self):
        print(f'{self.name} b')

    def do_c(self):
        print(f'{self.name} c')

list_of_methods_to_activate = ['do_a', 'do_b']

ps = PrintStuff()

for dewsired_method_to_activate in list_of_methods_to_activate:
    #activate dewsired_method_to_activate in ps
    ps.dewsired_method_to_activate() #would like that to work
```

How can I invoke these methods, using a list

Any help on that would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
list_of_methods_to_activate = ['do_a', 'do_b']

ps = PrintStuff()

for method in list_of_methods_to_activate:
    if hasattr(ps, method): # check's if method exists before calling
        getattr(ps, method)()
    else:
        print(f"{method} does not exists")
```